# How to install Teamviewer in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: software-installation, teamviewer

I've tried installing Teamviewer in my Ubuntu 14.10 64 bit.
Its done correctly.

Successfully installed.But not working with all the features of my UBuntu.

Just like , my friend couldn't help me to click on the settings via Teamviewer!

Answer (score 0):

You can install teamviewer via Ubuntu Software Center or you can use terminal to install teamviewer using this command.

```
sudo apt-get install teamviewer
```

and its full functionality free version of teamviewer as you see on windows.

Comment: I have it installed. Read my question completely...